# drawRect in Custom UIView off by height of navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm drawing a custom UIView that is sitting inside a xib whose ViewController is pushed onto a NavigationController.

Essentially the problem is that in the call to  `drawRect:(CGRect)rect`, rect has origin at (0,0) when it should have origin at (0,nav_bar_height).  Therefore, the following code, which draws an image

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

    // set up the image
    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageWithData:someData];

    // flip the image to the correct orientation
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, rect.size.height + rect.origin.y );
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);

    // draw the image
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, [img CGImage]);

    UIGraphicsPopContext();

}
```

This will cut off the top 30 pixels or so of the image and leave empty the bottom 30.

How can I account for the navigation bar height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing more about your view-structure, I risk being unhelpful, but let me know if the following helps at all: instead of using the `rect` parameter, which can be sort of unpredictable, try using the `bounds` of your custom view. In reality, I can't imagine why you'd be having this problem, unless your view is being overlapped with the navigation bar; I'd suggest checking to be sure this isn't so, in any case. Best of luck!

#### Update

*Looks like that didn't help.* Just offset your `y` parameter by `self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height`. So your code should look like:

```
//...
CGFloat dy = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height;
CGRect r = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y + dy, rect.size.width, rect.size.height - dy);
//...
CGContextDrawImage(context,r,img.CGImage);
//...
```

I hope that was more helpful.

Comment: The <code>bounds</code> parameter also has origin at (0,0).  The view isn't overlapped by the navigation bar, but the navigation bar pushes the entire view down (so (0,0) in the view doesn't match (0,0) in the window coordinates).  Thanks for the reply though, gets me thinking...

Comment: Works like a charm!  Awesome, really helped me out.

Comment: Glad that was helpful! At your convenience, it would be great if you'd choose this as the correct answer to your question. Cheers! :)